# Short story involving assassination by toy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story I read a few years ago. I do not remember exactly The impression I get is that this from 1950s/60s.

> It involves an important person who is at a high risk of
>   assassination. The person gets a toy as a gift. It seems to be a mock
>   factory or something similar. It is checked by security and found
>   harmless. He leaves it in his home, running. But as time passes, the
>   time passes and manufactures tiny soldiers who end up killing the
>   target.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe [Battleground](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleground_%28short_story%29), a short story by Stephen King? I read it in the *Night Shift* collection.

Summary: the protagonist is a hitman who has murdered a toy maker. Later he receives a package which turns out to be a collection of toy soldiers with vehicles. The soldiers attack him, and in the end the toys kill him with a miniature thermonuclear bomb.

The main difference to what you describe is that the toy soldiers are all already there in the package. No additional soldiers get built.

Comment: Close, but not what I am looking for. I specifically remember the toy being harmless in the beginning. It keep changing over multiple days produces the tool needed for the kill.

Comment: @BharatB Ok, this is a really long shot, but another story similar to what you describe is "War Game" by Philip Dick. There is no assassination, but there is a toy (a "soldier factory") suspected of being an enemy weapon. Over time, the toy assembles itself into a fortress and the soldiers attack it. Terran security forces suspect it is a weapon disguised as a toy, but in the end it turns out to be a red herring (the actual weapon is a different toy unrelated to the soldiers). It sounds different to your story, but maybe you misremembered?

Comment: @AndresF. that was the first one I thought of as well; why not turn it into an answer?

Comment: @SQB Yeah... the problem is that except for the toy soldiers, nothing else matches the description in the question :/ In "War Game" there is no very important person at risk of assassination, no assassination of anyone, and in the end the toy soldiers don't matter. It's such a long shot I don't feel comfortable posting it as an answer.