# Alien gifts of a game to subjugate the human race

Tags: story-identification, aliens, alien-invasion

I'm making myself crazy trying to remember the name of a short story I read years ago. It was in a short story collection, and may have been by Arthur C. Clark or Robert Heinlein.  I think it was in one of the Science Fiction Book Club's own "Best Science Fiction of [year] series..some time during the 70's or early 80's.

It's about an alien race who visits earth, bringing all sorts of gifts. Most of the story is about the government busy looking at the technological gifts with a paranoid eye. However, they let the games the aliens brought go out to the public, thinking them harmless.

The last few paragraphs are about a family playing a game. It's a box, the door of the box opens and tiny figures come out.  It subliminally teaches passiveness, to prepare humans to let the invaders take over.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: An existing question about the same story: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65321/testing-alien-toys-for-harm-story-and-author. It's PKDick's "War Game".

Comment: {nods} We just need the confirmation from Witchy Woman that it is the one...

Comment: That's the one.  Thanks!!!!  Now I can relax.  BTW...I'm new on this site.  Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: This is Pokemon Go?

Comment: @WitchyWoman: Not in this case. Had someone actually posted an answer below here, you would have clicked on the checkmark by the voting buttons to accept it. Incidentally, having your story-id question closed as a duplicate is by no means a criticism. Finding the right keywords is tricky.